# Object Building in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

I am getting an object structure like

```
Object--
   --- Object
        STRING1:VALUE
        STRING2:VALUE
        STRING3:VALUE 
   ---- OBJECT
         STRING1:VALUE
         STRING2:VALUE
         STRING3:VALUE
```

Now I want to filter this object because i need only STRING2:VALUE in the same object structure and need to a an structure similar to:

```
    Object
     STRING2:VALUE
    Object
     STRING2:VALUE
```

and  I need to do it in runtime can somebody please let me know ..

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand your wording here.  As I understand it you're either trying to make 1 object inherit from another:

```
public class myClass2 extends myClass1
{
    ...
}
```

Or you're trying for a static var:

```
public static var myValue:String = "myString";
```

If I'm misunderstanding I apologize.

Comment: I hAVE A OBJECT AND I NEED TO FILTER OUT THE OBJECT AND THEN CREATE A NEW OBJECT WITH ONE PROPERTY AND VALUE

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify further this question. It's difficult to understand the question.

Here's my understanding:

You have two Objects. ObjectA and ObjectB

Both objects have the following properties: string1:value, string2:value, string3:value

And you need to filter out string2 from the same objects and have the structure below:

> Object
>        STRING2:VALUE
>       Object
>        STRING2:VALUE

Is that right?

Comment: YES I NEED TO FILTER OUT THE OBJECT A AND CONSTRUCT THE SAME OBJECT EXCLUDING 2 PROPERTIES

Comment: Hi 

Can somebody give me some idea as to how to do it